# Audit in First Posts Queue Failed Though Correct Action was Taken

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing posts in the First Posts queue this morning, I ran into a very annoying "test". The answer was best described as "very low quality", so I flagged it as "very low quality", and somehow this caused me to fail the test! I was nearly out of votes for the day, and didn't want to waste a downvote on it.

[image]

I clicked "flag", marked it as very low quality, and then clicked "No Action Needed". What else should I have done, or is the test just broken? I literally preformed the exact action recommended in the **STOP!** message by flagging it!

Commenting was not appropriate, as other users had already commented! There was nothing new to add.

Now I've been locked out of reviews for 48 hours as this has happened twice. Can someone please fix this, or at least restore my review access?

Comment: Duplicate questions have no valid answers.

Comment: There is no answer, *other Will*, as they haven't fixed the bug yet.  All you can do is avoid it at this point.